# Powershell Foreach loop for mailbox

Tags: powershell

I am trying to document stats from mailboxes and have been using the following function , in this case shared mailboxes

```
Function Shared 
{
$strUserDetails=@()
$Filename = $Save_Path + $SFilename
$Shared_MBX = (Get-Mailbox -recipienttype sharedmailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -SortBy Name)
foreach ($mbx in $Shared_MBX)
{
$upn = Get-Mailbox $mbx.DisplayName | Select UserPrincipalName
$UserMailbox = get-mailboxstatistics -Identity $($mbx.DisplayName) | Select DisplayName, ItemCount,TotalItemSize 
$ItemSizeString = $UserMailbox.TotalItemSize.ToString()  
$strUserDetails = @(
$UserName = $upn
$ItemCount = $UserMailbox.ItemCount
$strMailboxSize = "{0:N2}" -f ($ItemSizeString.SubStrin(($ItemSizeString.IndexOf("(") + 1),($itemSizeString.IndexOf(" bytes") -  ($ItemSizeString.IndexOf("(") + 1))).Replace(",","")) 
)
  $strUserDetails += New-Object psobject -Property @{Items=$ItemCount;Size=$strMailboxSize;Name=$UserName}
} 
$strUserDetails | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Path $Filename
}
```

When I check the csv after it completes I would expect UPN, Itemcount , size for all shared mailbox but I only get one

Please tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: This is in Office 365

Answer (score 0):

```
$strUserDetails += New-Object psobject -Property @{Items=$ItemCount;Size=$strMailboxSize;Name=$UserName}
```

This is your problem, += here does nothing and acts as =. You are creating a new object for every mailbox, and overwriting. You will only get the last mailbox as a result.

> Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

Create an array before your foreach loop. Then, add a PSCustomObject to it for every loop. Example:

```
$strUserDetails = @()
foreach ($mbx in $Shared_MBX)
{
    $strUserDetails += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Items=$ItemCount
        Size=$strMailboxSize
        Name=$UserName
    }
}

$strUserDetails
```

Here's an example of solving the problem with an MCVE.

[image: My Testing]

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with the help you offered

```
Function Shared 
{
write-host "Running Shared Mailbox extract." -ForegroundColor Cyan
$Mailboxes = (Get-Mailbox -recipienttype sharedmailbox -ResultSize Unlimited)   
$Filename = $Save_Path + $SFilename
Write-Host "This will save the extract file to " $Filename
foreach ($mbx in $Mailboxes)
{
    $strUserDetails = @()
    $upn = Get-Mailbox $mbx.DisplayName | Select UserPrincipalName
    $UserMailbox = get-mailboxstatistics -Identity $($mbx.DisplayName) | Select DisplayName, ItemCount,TotalItemSize 
    $ItemSizeString = $UserMailbox.TotalItemSize.ToString()  
    $UserName = $upn.UserPrincipalName
    $ItemCount = $UserMailbox.ItemCount
    $strMailboxSize = "{0:N2}" -f ($ItemSizeString.SubString(($ItemSizeString.IndexOf("(") + 1),($itemSizeString.IndexOf(" bytes") - ($ItemSizeString.IndexOf("(") + 1))).Replace(",","")) 
    #Write-Host  "Accessing stats for mailbox:" $username
    $strUserDetails = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name=$UserName
        Items=$ItemCount
        Size=$strMailboxSize
        }
    $strUserDetails | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Path $Filename
}
Write-host "Completed Shared Extract" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
```